# postgresql store decimal value with trailing zero using type real

Tags: postgresql

i'm new to sql and trying to store a decimal value so that it gets stored truly as "6.0". for example,

```
INSERT INTO public.mytable(the_num) VALUES (6.0)
```

but the result is storing as "6" instead of "6.0" , of course any non-zero number like 6.1 or 6.5 is stored fine.

how can I store the value without having the trailing zero truncated ? is there some other data type i should be using?

Comment: what is real declaration of field?

Comment: all "natural" machine types, like int types, floating point have NOT version with and without trailing zero. These are simply number of concrete machine type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Real values are stored in binary format, so you can only decide in what form they will be shown. You can cast `real` values to `numeric` using `(precision, scale)` like this:

```
with my_table(the_num) as (
values
    (6.0::real),
    (6.1),
    (6.15)
)

select the_num, the_num::numeric(15,1), the_num::numeric(15,2)
from my_table

 the_num | the_num | the_num 
---------+---------+---------
       6 |     6.0 |    6.00
     6.1 |     6.1 |    6.10
    6.15 |     6.2 |    6.15
(3 rows)
```

Alternatively, you can use the function [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html), e.g.

```
select the_num, to_char(the_num, '999D9'), to_char(the_num, '999D99')
from my_table

 the_num | to_char | to_char 
---------+---------+---------
       6 |    6.0  |    6.00
     6.1 |    6.1  |    6.10
    6.15 |    6.2  |    6.15
(3 rows)
```

You can also use the `numeric` type instead of `real` in the table definition, e.g.:

```
create table my_table (
    the_num numeric(15, 2)
);
```

In this case the values will be stored with the defined scale.

Read more about [Numeric Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) in the documentation.